# Undefined index php mvc model

Tags: php

Undefined index: first_name

```
$view = $user->VIEW_EMP($connect);
    if (is_array($view)) {
        foreach($view as $key => $value){
            echo $view['first_name'];
        }
    }
```

Function:

```
static function VIEW_EMP($db){
    $sql = "SELECT * from employees LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    if($output = mysql_query($sql)):
            $columns = array();
            while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($output)):
                $columns[] = $result;
            endwhile;
        endif; 
       return $columns;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems typo.

```
echo $view['first_name'];
```

should be

```
echo $value['first_name'];
```

Comment: It works! Just a follow up question: why is still has a warning of undefined index if I put it this way: `$firstname .= "<tr> {$value['first_name']} </tr>";`

Comment: It should work fine. If you can provide surrounding code. Also check `var_dump($value);` if actually get `first_name` in it.